# file fetching approach

Tags: android, android-file

I am trying to read files from a particular folder in Android , i have two ways to do it:

1) use the typical approach is as follows

```
   File mainLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File folderLoc = new File(mainLoc , "/foldername/");
```

and after then fetch it using file name filters.

2) another way is to using BroadcastReceiver

```
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
   filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
```

so i really don't know wht is the difference between these approaches and which is efficient and represents the best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand these Intents are only triggered when external media is mounted or unmounted. So you can't use that approach unless these intents are triggered.